# Is it possible to consume an EJB 3 Web Service form a Java client without first generating client stubs/proxies?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

In most tutorials that I have seen so far people are using `wsconsume` or something like that to create classes that clients can use to access an EJB 3 Web Service.

Is this the only possible option? As my EJB's interface is annotated with `WebMethod`, `WebParam`, etc. isn't it possible to create a dynamic proxy or use runtime bytecode enhancement to create the proxies, etc. on the fly? E.g.:

```
MyWebService webService = WebServiceEnhance.getWebService(MyWebService.class);
webService.webMethod("foo");
```

A link to good reference material is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to deal with pure XML request/response.  You can trap sample request/response for the web service you want to consume using either [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) or [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and then use these samples as templates within your client.

Comment: helios, do you know any APIs that let me use my annotated WS interface through dynamic proxies? I want consuming the WS to be simplified by not generating stubs during compile time and parsing XML makes things more difficult in its own way.

Comment: This article might help: http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2007/04/webservice-client-using-dynamic-proxy.html